# Show $\mathbb R^n$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Show $\mathbb R^n$ is complete.

At this point, I am trying to work through the problem in my textbook, there is one step that I do not understand and would like explained. Here's my proof so far:

> Let $x_k = \{\xi_1^{(k)},\xi_2^{(k)},\ldots,\xi_n^{(k)}\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$. Then by definition, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $s, t > N$ then
> \begin{align*}
> d(x_s, x_t)&< \varepsilon\\
> \Bigg[\sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(\xi_j^{(s)} - \xi_j^{(t)}\bigg)^2\Bigg]^{\frac12}&< \varepsilon\\
> \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(\xi_j^{(s)} - \xi_j^{(t)}\bigg)^2&< \varepsilon^2
> \end{align*}
> which implies that $\bigg(\xi_j^{(s)} - \xi_j^{(t)}\bigg)^2 < \varepsilon^2$ or equivalently $\bigg\vert \xi_j^{(s)} - \xi_j^{(t)} \bigg\vert < \varepsilon$ for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. Hence $\xi_j^{(k)}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers for each $j$. Moreover since $\mathbb R$ is complete, every Cauchy sequence of real numbers is convergent. So it follows that $\xi_j^{(k)} \to \xi_j$. That is $\lim_{k \to \infty} \xi_j^{(k)} = \xi_j \in \mathbb R$ for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. Set $x = (\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_n)$ and observe that $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Here is where I get stuck; the book then does

> Since $d(x_s, x_t) < \varepsilon$, letting $t \to \infty$ we get $d(x_s, x) < \varepsilon$. Thus by definition $x_k \to x \in \mathbb R^n$ and we can conclude that $\mathbb R^n$ is complete.

My question is how we can just let $t \to \infty$ and get $x$? Using that reasoning couldn't we just say letting $k \to \infty$ we get $x$?

Moreover, a bit of a subquestion, my definition of Cauchy sequence is:

> A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $X = (X, d)$ is said to be Cauchy if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N = N(\varepsilon)$ such that $d(x_m, x_n) < \varepsilon$ for every $m, n > N$.

Is this the same as:?

> A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $X = (X, d)$ is said to be Cauchy if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N = N(\varepsilon)$ such that $d(x_s, x_t) < \varepsilon$ for every $s, t > N$.

Also, I am using Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis and this is example on page 33.

Comment: Those last two definitions are clearly equivalent; you just used $m,n$ in one of them and $s,t$ in the other.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting confused with the naming of the sequence $(x_n)$ and using that $n$ in the definition.

Comment: Ah yes, strictly speaking the latter definition is better. Or change the $(x_n)$ to $(x_k)$ in the first one. Otherwise you are right: it is confusing and somewhat incorrect.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think the two main books I'm working through use the first notation, I just wanted to make sure the second approach was still correct and that there wasn't some hidden meaning in using $n$ twice that I couldn't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem to me like they're using the fact being proven in the proof itself. Maybe I missed something. This is what I'd do with the last part.

> For any $\varepsilon$, select $N_i$ such that if $s>N_i$ then $|\xi^s_i - \xi_i| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$. This can be done since $\xi_i^s\to\xi_i$. Let $N = \max\{N_1,\ldots,N_n\}$. Therefore if $s>N$, then
>   $$d(x_s,x)=\sqrt{\sum_1^n(\xi^s_i-\xi_i)^2}<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Well they explicitly say "since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete," so presumably they first explained that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete elsewhere and are now using that fact to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also complete.

Comment: At the stage they say, $t \to \infty$ and replace $x_t$ with $x$, they're assuming $\{x_t\}$ converges to $x$. Circular reasoning.

Comment: "$\mathbb{R}$ is complete" was only used to show that the sequence of components $\xi_i^s \to \xi_i$.

Comment: No, they define $x$ to be the vector whose coordinates are the limits of the coordinates of $x_k$ which exist since they showed the coordinates to be Cauchy sequences and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Then they write down the inequality from before. Then they take the limit of the individual coordinates as $t \to \infty$ in the inequality to get a new inequality. Then they see that this inequality actually reads $d(x_s,x) < \epsilon$. Now they conclude that actually $x_k \to x$ in the metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$. No circular reasoning.

Comment: So why even bother with the inequality since clearly $x_k$ will tend to $x$ for just the same reason $x_t$ does. Why didn't they say, "Take the limit of the individual coordinates of ${x_k}$ (original sequence) as $k\to \infty$ and you get $x$."

Comment: While it doesn't seem circular anymore, I think they could have made it much easier then. My answer justifies being able to look at the limit of a sequence as the limit of its individual coordinates, which I'm not sure whether they'd explained before.

Comment: I mostly agree. However the inequality is more or less just a precise way of saying that sequences converge in a $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if their components converge in $\mathbb{R}$ which is of course the crucial part of the proof.